# How to export mysql database structure only throught command line, but export some specific tables data from the specified in list

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to export MySQL database through command line with following two conditions as below,

1. Export database tables structure only.
2. But at the time of Exporting data, I want to export specified table data and structure both that are mention in command.

I have a database which contains 60 tables, and from them, one table named `Country` contains the static values.  So I want to export its data too in the exported file, and rest of the tables contain only structure in exported file.

Can any one suggest me MySQL command to dump the database based on above conditions?

Answer (score 1):

**First method:**

`mysqldump --no-data -h <host> -u <username> -p<password> <database> > tables.sql`

This will dump your database table structures into the file `tables.sql`.

The `--no-data` option specifies that table content is not dumped.

**Second method:**

(This can be useful if you want to more with the generated `.sql` file in batch processing.)

- Use the `show create table` command to see the actual command to create a table.
- Create a Bash script that executes that MySQL command for every table that you want to export. Pipe the output from `show create table <table_name>` to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to fire 2 separate commands for that.

```
mysqldump -u root -p password --no-data --ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name db_name > db_name.sql
```

Above query will dump all the structure of database without your country table's structure and data.

```
mysqldump -u root -p password db_name tbl_name >> db_name.sql
```

And this one will dump Country table's structure and data into the same file.

Comment: Thanks onkar the above solution work correctly.  But what if suppose we have multiple static tables to be ignored.

Comment: you can use multiple ignore statements in single command
--ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name1  --ignore-table=db_name.tbl_name2
like this.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you are successful in what you were  trying to do.